Passing In Tailwindcss Classes to Component Library Not Working
So, I am building a React component library (like the world needs another one) and an app on top of it. When I pass in Tailwind classes to the components from the app, the passed classes don't get compiled.
App Component
export const DataList = () => {

// ...

  return (
    <div>
      <List className="p-10"> <<<<<------ Passing the class to the library component
        {data.map(d => (
          // Ignore warning: key is being set on the li in the ListItem component
          <ListItem id={d.id}>
            <div>{d.title}</div>
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  );
};

Library Component
export const List = ({
  children,
  restProps,
  className // p-10
}) => {
  return (
    <ul {...restProps} className={className}> <--- Does not get compiled into my dist/style.css
      {children}
    </ul>
  );
};

Here's a few more files that might help
rollup.config.mjs
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss';
import tailwindConfig from './tailwind.config.mjs';
import packageJson from './package.json' assert { type: 'json' };

export default [
  {
    input: 'lib/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        name: 'data-app',
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: 'umd',
        sourcemap: true
      },
      {
        name: 'data-app',
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: 'es',
        sourcemap: true
      }
    ],
    plugins: [
      postcss({
        config: {
          path: './postcss.config.mjs'
        },
        extensions: ['.css'],
        inject: {
          insertAt: 'top'
        },
        extract: 'style.css',
        plugins: [tailwindcss(tailwindConfig)]
      }),

      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' })
    ]
  }
];


tailwind.config.mjs
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ['./lib/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mjs,css}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {}
  },
  plugins: []
};

tsconfig.js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "esnext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["lib"]
}

Been through dozens of docs, reddit posts, and other stack overflows. Any similar situation seems to have a fix that doesn't work for me. A lot of what I've seen has told me to set things up exactly as I have them.
What I current have works really well if I'm adding the tailwind classes directly into the library component.

Are utility classes working for general HTML elements such as <div> in the same component?

Consider checking the App component code is covered by the content file globs in the Tailwind configuration.

@KarsonJo -- Yeah, no problems there.

@Wongjn -- I'm good on that. It will compile all the classes directly added to the element. It's just the ones passed in that don't compile

Checking in the browser, does the p-10 class of the <List> component not appear in the element's style list at all, or is it overridden?

@KarsonJo -- It does show up in the DOM, it just doesn't show up in the CSS. I'm wondering if it might be a build order thing...

Sorry, my previous question might have been a bit ambiguous. Are you referring to its name p-10 appearing in the class="..." attribute, or its property value appearing in the Styles section of the Debug tools?

Gotcha... I think... The p-10 value does appear in the <List>'s class attribute but it does not appear in the Styles section.
